# Why is this program losing track of the count?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have two list variables: descriptions and amounts. These lists are created by appending certain parts of each index of a nested list (transaction info). Every Item in Transaction info is a list that follows this template (Date, Description, more info, more info, amount, balance). Here is my code:

```
    dates = []
    descriptions = []
    amounts = []
    #transaction info is a nested list of each row of my excel sheet
    transaction_info = select_all(bank_statements)
    i=0
    #skips the first row because of headers
    for row in transaction_info:
        if i<1:
            i+=1
        else:
            #breaks down row cell by cell
            for cell in row:
                if cell == row[0]:
                    dates.append(cell)
                if cell == row[1]:
                    full_desc = str(cell)+str(row[2])+str(row[3])
                    if 'None' in full_desc:
                        none_strip = full_desc.strip('None')
                        descriptions.append(none_strip)
                        i+=1
                    elif full_desc in descriptions:
                        descriptions.append(f'{full_desc}{i}')
                        i+=1
                    else:
                        descriptions.append(full_desc)
                        i+=1
                if cell == row[4]:
                    strcell = str(cell)
                    amounts.append(strcell)
    i+=1
```

For some reason when I run:

```
    for desc in enumerate(descriptions):
        print(desc)
    for amnt in enumerate(amounts):
        print(amnt)
```

they are different lengths. What am I doing wrong? How is it losing count?

For reference, it works fine up until row 61.

I am using OpenPyxl.

I am expecting the Amounts and Descriptions lists to line up so I can put them back together later.

Comment: If it works fine upto row 61, then add a print statement with `if i>58: print(locals())` to check what happens before and after. My guess is that there is a problem in your data file if it works for 60 lines and then suddenly breaks

Comment: Well, you append to `amounts` under certain conditions and you append to `descriptions` under other conditions. Clearly those conditions are not always the same, but since this is not a reproducible example, it's pretty hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For whatever reason, if there was a blank cell it would just count the descriptions multiple times and add it to the list unnecessarily. I filled in the empty cells on the excel sheet I was pulling data from and it fixed this bug. I am going to add some conditionals to account for this.